# Query on giving access to team members on TFS & SharePoint

Tags: security, sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

Let's say I have a team of 10 members. I want to give access to both TFS & SharePoint Server to all team members. What is the right approach??

Shall I create a AD security group & add all the team member into that group.Now on TFS create a team & add that AD security group into that TFS team. On SP as well give permission to same AD group.

Is this the right approach or something else could be better?

Atul Sureka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role based access control more commonly known as RBAC would be the best practice method to approach this ([documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-role-based-management-in-sharepoint.aspx)). This would allow you to assign various roles to your security groups which you could then use in SharePoint and tfs (Or in future potentially Visual Studio Online).

Alternatively your second approach using the same security groups in both systems would also be ideal and is in essence a simpler approach to the same problem, just with less potential for growth.